# Installing GDAL with Python on Windows

Tags: python, gdal, installation, windows

Can anyone explain how to install GDAL/OGR with Python on Windows?

I have Windows Vista and I have tried following the information on the website and it does not seem to bind the **.exe* files for me.

Can someone describe the process, including links to the files/folders I will need?

I have now tried to run the GDAL setup with minGW, but this has also failed:

[image: GDAL_FAIL]

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Unless you have good reasons not to, I'd definitely recommend starting with the [OSGeo4W installer](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki), which can install multiple different versions of GDAL and their relevant Python bindings. It works great and dramatically simplifies the Windows deployment story. Specifically, you'll want to install [pkg-gdal-python](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki/pkg-gdal-python), which is within 'Libs' in the installer tree.

Answer (score 68):

### Updated answer

Use [Christoph Gohlke's Geospatial library wheels for Python on Windows](https://github.com/cgohlke/geospatial-wheels/)  packages, which are bundled as GitHub releases, e.g. [v2023.4.22](https://github.com/cgohlke/geospatial-wheels/releases/tag/v2023.4.22).

### Original answer - stopped working May 2023

You can download GDAL wheel package from [Christoph Gohlke's Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal).

It can be installed from cmd.exe using something like:

```
c:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install GDAL-X.Y.Z-cp27-none-win_XYZ.whl
```

(You should install [NumPy from the same place](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) using a similar command)

While the package is not built by OSGeo or GDAL developers, it is a high quality distribution with support for the latest versions of GDAL compiled for 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Python. No external libraries need to be added or managed!

It even sets the `GDAL_DATA` environment variable, if it is not set, and includes a `PostgreSQL` driver to read data from PostGIS.

Comment: It looks like that site/page is no longer available.

Comment: Thanks @HughStimson, this was scheduled to happen eventually. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 17):

Another option is to install the **Anaconda Python** distribution which has packages for **GDAL**. If you are going to be doing a lot of work using GDAL with other Python packages (scipy, pandas, scikit-learn etc.,) this might be a better option than OSGeo4W. On the other hand if you want to use Python in combination with a number of open-source remote sensing and GIS packages (GRASS, QGIS etc.,) OSGeo4W is probably the better option.

You can get the full Anaconda distribution from: https://www.continuum.io/downloads which contains a lot of Python packages aimed at 'data science' or a minimal installation from http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html

As part of the installation it will prompt you to add to the main path (so it is available from any terminal).

Once set up GDAL can be installed into a new environment using:

```
conda create -n gdal_env -c conda-forge gdal
```

Then activating it as shown when the command finishes. Installing into a new environment is recommended to avoid conflicts with other packages and make sure the environmental variables required are set.

I've suggested installing from the conda-forge channel (https://conda-forge.github.io/) as they are very active in keeping their GDAL builds up to date and making sure they work against a lot of libraries.

Once installed packages can be updated from within the environment using:

```
conda update gdal
```

Answer (score 16):

I find OSGEO4W a poor solution because it creates a whole parallel universe, almost like a virtual machine.  I was able to install GDAL and use it in python following the steps outlined [here](http://cartometric.com/blog/2011/10/17/install-gdal-on-windows/) (this is the link provided by @sys49152).

It sends you to gisinternals.com. Take the link to "stable releases" to get to:
http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php

Now you have to choose between 32 and 64 bits and different Microsoft Visual C++ compiler versions. Note that this has to match your python version, not your OS. In my case I have a 64 bit windows, but a 32 bit python 2.7 (that shipped with ArcGIS).

To see what you have you can run python on the command line and a message like this:

```
C:\>python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

So I need to use "release-1500"

I selected: `MSVC 2013/win32   release-1500-gdal-1-11-3-mapserver-6-4-2`

(the build version numbers will change over time)

I first downloaded and installed the "Generic installer for the GDAL core components": `gdal-111-1500-core.msi`

And added the path and other variables as described [here](http://cartometric.com/blog/2011/10/17/install-gdal-on-windows/).

Add to path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL`
Create environmental variables: 
`GDAL_DATA =  C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal-data`
`GDAL_DRIVER_PATH = C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdalplugins`

Then, I downloaded and installed the python module for python 2.7 `GDAL-1.11.3.win32-py2.7.msi`

And after that, in python I was able to do

```
from osgeo import gdal
ds = gdal.Open('file.tif')
```

etc.

Answer (score 11):

Here is another tutorial which explains very simple and easy way of installing GDAL v1.8 with Python v2.7 on a Windows XP/7 system.

http://elrobis.com/blog/2011/10/17/install-gdal-on-windows/

> 1. Install Python
> 2. Install the GDAL binaries published by Tamas Szekeres
> 3. Append your environment Path variable
> 4. Add the GDAL_DATA environment variable
> 5. Finally, perform a quick test to make sure everything worked.

Answer (score 6):

I know The OSGEO installer was mentioned, but as GuidoS said it doesn't work unless you're on the osgeow shell, which is fine and dandy if all you're doing is basic python. Chances are if you're not, you either have to reinstall the package and then have to run your app/plugin from that folder or have to compile all the dependencies for gdal and install it again.

What works for me is:

- In PyDev/Eclipse (not my primary IDE), I add the list of libraries to the default python interpreter
- Use the built in console to run the files

Answer (score 5):

Its really not that difficult to do. I've compiled it many times before using Visual Studio without any issues. Just follow the directions here: [link text](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingOnWindows).

It's pretty straightforward, just read through the well documented makefile.vc and set the appropriate directories, notably the Python one. Once it's built you should have a Python module built which you can then copy to your Python installation, which I've always done maually, but there is probably a more approriate method.

Answer (score 5):

Another current, very easy option for downloading the gdal binaries is at  [Christoph Gohlke’s site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

Comment: That link is also now dead.

Answer (score 5):

The site listed by @Mike is for unofficial binaries - which was very useful when 64 bit GDAL was not readily available (as per the time he wrote his reply), but it has been now for some time. I have added this alternative answer here as, although I have mentioned it many times, it still keep cropping up and this wiki may be a better place to put it.

If you want to install just the GDAL Binaries for Python on a windows machine I would get the installers from the excellent [GIS Internals](http://www.gisinternals.com/) Site.  This site is linked from the official [GDAL/OGR Binaries](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries) page.  This gives you access to GDAL through a normal Python install without any need for using the osgeow shell.  The binaries here are regularly maintained and compiled against a variety of versions of Visual Studio (so choose depending on what runtimes you have installed).

Answer (score 4):

Like the other contributors, I advice to choose [OSGEO4W installer](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki).

If for any reasons, you don't want or can't use it, 
see the Python packages documentation on gdal
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/

You will discover, for example, there are [gdal binaries](http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/win32/) on OSGEO website

Answer (score 2):

I use [FWTools](http://fwtools.maptools.org/) in Windows XP. It includes a Python installation with the GDAL libraries. After installation, just run your Python scripts from the *FWTools Shell*.

Answer (score 2):

I normally install using `pipwin` command. It is straightforward and easy way to install the latest version of `GDAL`.

```shell
pip install pipwin
pipwin install gdal
```

If it throws the `404 error`, you may need to refresh the pipwin and try again,

```shell
pipwin refresh
pipwin install gdal
```

Comment: I will try this...