# Import Error while Importing osgeo package

Tags: python, qgis, gdal, osgeo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install GDAL with Python on windows?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/how-to-install-gdal-with-python-on-windows)

I have downloaded Fwtools for python2.5 from    http://fwtools.maptools.org(windows installer) after installing it, it was giving error as Unable to import osgeo. Then I checked the whole FWtools for osgeo but nothing was there ..

can anyone guide me how can I get "osgeo" and "gdal/ogr" package for the Python
(as I don't have any python documentation for osgeo and the command        pydoc -g osgeo also doesn't work)

Presently I am using all these packages from inside the Qgis Console..Can't I have the same package for my python bundle..

Comment: Please consider accepting some answers to your previous questions. It's generally considered good practice to reward the people who take the time to answer your questions.

Comment: I didn't know that Underdark . Thanks for informing this

Comment: I think that this question have been already answered, see [for example this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/how-to-install-gdal-with-python-on-windows).

Answer (score 2):

I've been using GDAL/OGR library with Python 2.5 for quite a while. I downloaded Windows installation binary from http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/win32/1.6/ and installed it. After that, you need to set up the Environment variable (path) under Windows. This way, it should be available to you enywhere outside QGIS.

https://www.packtpub.com/python-geospatial-development/book 
I found this book a great resource if you do python GIS development. It guides you through installations of various libraries as well.