# Why does a TIF file lose projection information when a pixel value is changed?

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff

I am trying to change the pixel value of a tif file (containing projection information) but after the pixel value is changed it is losing projection information.

I am using the Python imaging library for this and the code is like this

```
import Image
im = Image.open("some tif file")
im.putpixel((2,3),0)
```

So please help me in solving this ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a Python library that supports the [GeoTIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoTIFF) format. Libraries that support only the [TIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF) file discard the projection and geotransform metadata when they are saved. GDAL is the most used open source Python library for reading/writing spatially aware rasters. So, for your example:

```
from osgeo import gdal

# Load file, and access the band and get a NumPy array
src = gdal.Open('myfile.tif', gdal.GA_Update)
band = src.GetRasterBand(1)
ar = band.ReadAsArray()

# Assign a new raster pixel value
ar[2,3] = 0

# Save/close the file
band.WriteArray(ar)
del ar, band, src
```

Comment: Thanks Mike ... I will you please suggest me some good resource where i can get the gdal related stuffs for Python..              Because I know C++ stuffs for gdal but i get some problems in converting that to the python

Comment: Installing Python bindings for GDAL is simple for most Linux distros. For Windows, [there are a few](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/how-to-install-gdal-with-python-on-windows) with my personal favourite installer being a simple [installer from Christoph Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal)