# Change GeoTIFF photometric

Tags: python, gdal

I have a set of GeoTIFF having `photometric = palette`, I need to convert it to a `greyscale` image without losing associated data values.
I need to do using `Python` or `ArcGIS`.

Changing the color could be done by setting the `tiff` `tag` to `1` (`Luminance` mode) using `Python` module `PIL` (Pillow):

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("test_in.tif")
im.tag[262] = 1
im.save("test_out.tif")
```

The problem is that the generated file does not have any spatial ref., what should I do ?

Sample : [image sample](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5Mo9EiQNwfmVG9tTDBfSWR1Z3M)

Comment: If this is your homework, did your teacher give you any hint about what to try?

Comment: No it is not  I'm working on a project

Comment: Write that as an answer and tell which tools can be used for such editing.

Comment: I updated the question, it is an uncomplete answer, the image lost it's projection infos.

Comment: @user30184 do you have any idea doing this using  `gdal`

Comment: Did it work for you trying out my answer? It seems to me that you just missed to pass along the tags when saving the image.

Answer (score 1):

Here comes a workaround with GDAL.

Create a virtual raster file with gdalbuildvrt http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html

```
gdalbuildvrt palettetest.vrt palette.tif
```

Open the palettetest.vrt file with text editor

Change

```
<ColorInterp>Palette</ColorInterp>
```

into

```
<ColorInterp>Gray</ColorInterp>
```

and remove the whole ColorTable section

```
<ColorTable>
      <Entry c1="120" c2="120" c3="120" c4="255" />
      <Entry c1="72" c2="72" c3="72" c4="255" />
     ...
 </ColorTable>
```

Now you have a virtual grayscale image that you can use with GDAL and QGIS as is.

```
gdalinfo palettetest.vrt
Driver: VRT/Virtual Raster
Files: palettetest.vrt
       palette.tif
Size is 1728, 1977
Coordinate System is `'
...
Band 1 Block=128x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
```

You can materialize it with gdal_translate

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff palettetest.tif grayscale.tif
```

The result in QGIS with min-max stretch between pixel values 2 and 82.

[image]

Comment: The result was a black image, each pixel contains a value, I guess this is similar to changing symbology.

Comment: Very hard to say without having a sample of your image and what you await when you wrote "without losing associated data values". Sometimes palette has only a few entries in the beginning of the scale, sometimes the whole 0-255 range is utilized.

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: I meant to put a test image for downloading so that others could play with similar data that you have.

Comment: already done, did you check the update?

Comment: Yes, and added the screen capture of my result as you can see above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass along the TAGs as "tiffinfo" when saving:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("test_in.tif")
im.tag[262] = 1
im.save("test_out.tif", tiffinfo=im.tag)
```

This way, you shouldn't loose any of the meta-data.
Also, the updated EXIF-TAGs, in your case TAG "262", should appear in your output file.

If you want to compare input and output files as for the TIFF-Tags,
just use the following command lines:

```
exiftool -D -G -a -u -U -f -s "test_in.tif"
exiftool -D -G -a -u -U -f -s "test_out.tif"
```

[exiftool](https://exiftool.org/) is a cross-platform command line tool.
I'm using it on my Linux Lubuntu 18.04 OS.
In my opinion, it displays the TIFF-Tags in the most complete way, since python libraries like

- exifread
- PIL
- tifffile
- skimage.external.tifffile

seem to be blind on the eye of GeoTIFF-Tags, as they only display EXIF-Tags.

Answer (score 0):

You are losing geo information such as spatial reference because you are using a library that only supports TIFF, not GeoTIFF (there's a difference).

See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/16840/29005 for more info.

Comment: I understand, Do you have any idea to change the color of the `GeoTIFF`s using `gdal`, because i've already googled this but in vain.

Comment: Changing the tiff mode to luminance is not "changing color", it just tells image viewers to treat the tiff as a greyscale. Look into gdal's setMetaData/setMetaDataItem and getMetadata/getMetaDataItem functions for this kind of change.