# How to install GDAL for python on windows and use for spatial purpose?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install GDAL with Python on windows?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/how-to-install-gdal-with-python-on-windows)

I am trying to copy GDAL osgeo to my python library file to run my python program for gis function. following is code.

import osgeo.ogr

shapefile = osgeo.ogr.Open("tl_2009_us_state.shp")
numLayers = shapefile.GetLayerCount()

print ("Shapefile contains %d layers" % numLayers)
print

for layerNum in range(numLayers):
    layer = shapefile.GetLayer(layerNum)
    spatialRef = layer.GetSpatialRef().ExportToProj4()
    numFeatures = layer.GetFeatureCount()
    print ("Layer %d has spatial reference %s" % (layerNum, spatialRef))
    print ("Layer %d has %d features:" % (layerNum, numFeatures))
    print

```
for featureNum in range(numFeatures):
    feature = layer.GetFeature(featureNum)
    featureName = feature.GetField("NAME")

    print ("Feature %d has name %s" % (featureNum, featureName))
```

But u able to find missing .py file as some error. Can any one say step is write or any other steps for installing.

Comment: Done using .exe