# Creating a mask with transparent pixels in Python

Tags: python, raster, geotiff-tiff, image, masking

I have a GeoTIFF image with pixel intensities ranging between certain values. Let's say between -2 and 2 (the image is normalized). I have a certain threshold which interests me, let's sat 1. I would like to create a NEW image that makes all the pixels that where previously larger than 1 to now have the maximum value, 2, or just some constant value. And all other pixels to be transparent.

I'm very new to this so I hope my question is understandable.

Comment: What software are you using?  Is this an ESRI question with Spatial Analyst, or an Open Source, QGIS, question?

Comment: What is ESRI? I'm sorry. I just recently started working on these things. At the moment I just play around on images with python and then visualize my results using ENVI. What program would you recommend, by the way, for visualization and such? I don't think im loving ENVI.

Comment: [ESRI](http://www.esri.com) is a company that makes a commercial GIS package called ArcGIS.  It is a good product, but rather expensive.  An open source option for visualizing raster data is [Quantum GIS](http://www.qgis.org).

Comment: You'll find a ton of information in those slides: http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Python I'd recommend using the [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) library, which has it's own [Python bindings](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInPython). Assuming you've got both GDAl (see [this GIS StackExchange question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/how-to-install-gdal-with-python-on-windows) for details on how to install on windows) and numpy installed, your code could look something like:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

#Open our original data as read only
dataset = gdal.Open("file_path.tif", gdal.GA_ReadOnly)

#Note that unlike the rest of Python, Raster Bands in GDAL are numbered
#beginning with 1.
#I suspect this is to conform to the landsat band naming convention
band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)

#Read in the data from the band to a numpy array
data = band.ReadAsArray()
data = data.astype(numpy.float)

#Use numpy, scipy, and whatever Python to make some output data
#That for ease of use should be an array of the same size and dimensions
#as the input data.
out_data = np.where(abs(data) > 1., 2., -9999.)
#Note -9999 is a convenience value for null - there's no number for
#transparent values - it's just how you visualise the data in the viewer

#And now we start preparing our output
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
metadata = driver.GetMetadata()

#Create an output raster the same size as the input
out = driver.Create("out_file.tif",
                    dataset.RasterXSize,
                    dataset.RasterYSize,
                    1, #Number of bands to create in the output
                    gdal.GDT_Float32)

#Copy across projection and transform details for the output
out.SetProjection(dataset.GetProjectionRef())
out.SetGeoTransform(in_dataset.GetGeoTransform()) 

#Get the band to write to
out_band = out.GetRasterBand(1)

#And write our processed data
out_band.WriteArray(out_data)
```

Comment: This looks amazing, I suspect just what I need. Let me try it out and get back to you. By the way, if there is no number for transparent values I will have to indicate my visualization (e.g. ENVI) that I want X intensity values to be transparent?  @om_henners

Comment: That's right @JEquihua - most visualisation tools have the option of setting values transparent.

Comment: I noticed that you're assigning "metadata", but don't seem to be doing anything with it.  What does "metadata" provide, and how would you use it?