# gdal ImportError in python on Windows

Tags: python, gdal, windows-xp

Trying to import gdal for Python 2.7.3 on Windows XP:

```
>>> import gdal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gdal.py", line 2, in <module>
    from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 21, in <mo
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 17, in swit_helper
  _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Following suggestions from [Installing GDAL with Python on windows?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/how-to-install-gdal-with-python-on-windows) and elsewhere, here's what I've done so far:

- removed all versions of python and started with a clean install of 2.7.3
- installed gdal with the OSGeo4W installer
- installed the native Win gdal binaries from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
- added `C:\OSGeo4W\bin;` first in my `Path` variable
- tried `from osgeo import gdal`
- launched python from within the OSGeo4W Shell
- run the procedure outlined in http://cartometric.com/blog/2011/10/17/install-gdal-on-windows/

The result is the same. Any other ideas about how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Did you install Python using OSGeo4W?

Comment: gdal19.dll is not in your path.  Edit the environment variable and try again.  Also, you should use the import: from osgeo import gdal.

Comment: @NathanW I had not - I installed 2.7.2 and tried again - no change.

Comment: @kyle gdal19.dll is in C:\OSGeo4W\bin which is in my path, and the result is the same when I try `from osgeo`.

Comment: Are you sure the versions match up for your python bindings and your osgeo install?  I don't use windows that much.  Can you check your gdal version to be sure it's 1.9.2: gdalinfo --version

Comment: Have you tried, in a command line, 'cd'ing to the site-packages/osgeo, launching python, and importing from the directory that gdal.py is in?  This will let you know if the issue is PATH related.

Comment: @JayLaura Yep - I'm in the dir, gdal.py and ogr.py are both sitting there looking at me, but I get the same error.

Comment: @kyle Interesting: `gdalinfo --version` throws an error: "Unable To Locate Component: This application has failed to start because ogdi_32b1.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem." This leads me to this thread: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.osgeo.osgeo4w/359 ... and I am on a 64-bit machine. (The 2nd line of gdal.py says it's 2.0.8, btw.) So maybe I'm out of luck.

Comment: I always use the gdal core and bindings from gisinternals.com/sdk (I use the development version though, 1.10dev).  I am guessing 2.0.8 is the swig version that was used to create the bindings, not the gdal version.  Open the osgeo4w shell (it sets the proper variables) and try to start python and import gdal

Comment: Old question, but it popped up on my feed today. I always use the binary install: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal

Answer (score 23):

Condensed procedure outlined in http://cartometric.com/blog/2011/10/17/install-gdal-on-windows/ for Windows 7, 32 Bits, to install **GDAL PYTHON**:

1) Install Python.

I installed Python 2.7.9 from https://www.python.org/

2) Install the GDAL binaries published by Tamas Szekeres.

First, I launched IDLE (Python GUI) noting the following values: "MSC v.1500" and "on win32":

[image]

In this link: http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php

Click in the magenta link of the below image:

[image]

Click in the magenta links of the below image for download and install **gdal-111-1500-core.msi** and **GDAL-1.11.1.win32-py2.7.msi**:

[image]

3) Append your environment Path variable

[image]

[image]

After click in **Edit** and search for **Path**, add:

> ;C:\Program Files\GDAL

**DON'T FORGET the ; character before C:\Prog... and click OK three times**:

[image]

4) Add the GDAL_DATA environment variable (one click in **New** for each variable: **gdal-data** and **gdalplugins**)

**DON'T FORGET click OK three times**:

[image]

[image]

5) Finally, perform a quick test to make sure everything worked.

Launch IDLE (Python GUI) and type **from osgeo import gdal** [Enter]:

[image]

I didn't get gdal ImportError in python on my Windows 7 system.

Note: **import gdal** is deprecated.

Comment: I have tried with all above explained methods but it show error like this:
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

Comment: I know that this method works for 7 and 8 Windows systems and python 2.7 with 32 bits. If you have different conditions you should carefully read in each link those that match in your own system.

Comment: Thanks!I have recently windows 10 and I am screwed up. I installed in my office several computers it worked perfectly but not at home it is not working at all. I am hang up for several hours. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Same boat as you, @ShiuliPervin. It's a joke... so difficult to install this. I have literally spent all day trying to get gdal installed. Ridiculous! Apparently, though, you can do this with scipi http://www.hydro.washington.edu/~jhamman/hydro-logic/blog/2013/10/12/plot-netcdf-data/ as well as python-netcdf4

Comment: I meant netcdf4-python: netcdf4-python https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf4-python

Comment: One problem may arise! ArcGIS installs python in the custom folder i.e. `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3` you may need to show this path to the python bindings to be installed.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend to place the path to GDAL in the PATH variable BEFORE(!!) the python path. In this way you avoid the fact that python can not find the necessary gdal.dlls

Answer (score 4):

Similarly, I placed

> C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL;

at the very first in the **Path** of *System Variables*. Issue solved after 1 day of searching the web. Using Python 2.7.10, 32 bit, Windows 8.

Comment: This solved my problem completely! I had Arc Desktop installed first and then installed gdal without an issue once I did this.

Comment: This was an important step in the solution for me. For the rest, check the RobertH community wiki and my comments below it:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/installing-gdal-with-python-on-windows/181833#181833

Answer (score 0):

If installing via whl you must install the visual-c redistribute to get gdal to work!

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads