# How to setup GDAL setting for python using OSGEO4W?

Tags: gdal, python-2.7, osgeo4w

I have installed OSGEO4W installer. In that I have installed Express Desktop install option. QGIS GDAL uDig and GRASS GIS were installed in C:/OSGEO4W64. 
I have added 'C:/OSGEO4W64/bin' in the path.

But still getting error for running - 'gdal_retile.py' from command prompt as  not recognising as aninternal or external command.

On using OSGEO4W shell, on running 'gdal_retile.py' and other gdal python file, I was getting -

> ImportError DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

I am using Windows 7 64 bit, python in OSGEO4W was Python-2.7.

**EDITION**

After following the condensed procedure I am getting following error on running `from osgeo import gdal` in IDLE

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from osgeo import gdal
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

[image]

Comment: Can you include the equivalent image of this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/96uKx.png

Comment: @xunilk I included, along with the error

Comment: You said: "I am using Windows 7 64 bit". Did you install the correct version of Python 2.7.9 for 64 bits (with Windows x86-64 MSI installer)? This is the link: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.9/python-2.7.9.amd64.msi

Comment: @xunilk I again installed python 2.7.9 for amd 64 but still no luck . Getting same error

Comment: What is the new version of this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XD59g.png ?

Answer (score 3):

No error if you put only **gdal_retile**. See image below:

[image]

If you want to run gdal in the IDLE Python GUI or in the MS-DOS Console you can try this:

[gdal ImportError in python on Windows](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44958/gdal-importerror-in-python-on-windows/143140#143140)

Comment: Problem is that I have to run this command from cmd and in cmd I am getting the mentioned error for both with extension and without extension

Comment: In this case you need the condensed procedure outlined in: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44958/gdal-importerror-in-python-on-windows/143140#143140

Comment: I have followed the provided procedure but still I am getting error, but this time different error. I have edited my question and included the error.