# Not able to import GDAL into Python env

Tags: gdal

I am new to Python scripting.  Can anyone tell me if there is any way to import gdal into Python environment (ArcGIS Desktop 10). I am getting error while importing. Please check attached picture.[image]

Comment: It seems to me that pyGDAL is not a part of standard ArcGIS install. Do you install gdal and it python bindings into the arcgis python?

Comment: You need to do this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44958/gdal-importerror-in-python-on-windows/143140#143140

Comment: Yes I have installed GDAL from (http://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1500-gdal-mapserver.zip) and also added the gdal path to variable settings in my system. My python version is 2.6, may be this version supporting gdal or not I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Add the GDAL_DATA environment variable pointing to (C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal-data) and GDAL_DRIVER_PATH  pointing to (C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdalplugins)

Comment: I have added path to the Environment variable. Still not working.

Comment: Have you tried with other IDE? Such as PyScripter or PyCharm?

Comment: Do you have background geoprocessing  64 bit installed? If so, another instance of python 2.x, 64 bit, is installed, so the python console may be getting that one, and the gdal you installed is not for that one. Try another IDE, where you can choose which python interpreter to execute, in case you have more than one.