# ImportError: DLL load failed with error code when I try to import GDAL from the Python console

Tags: python, gdal

I've installed `GDAL` from the wheel files available [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal) on Python 3.4. I'm using an old version of Python because one of the packages I need doesn't work yet on Python 3.6.

When I try to import gdal in Python with a simple `from osgeo import gdal`, I get the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 37, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795
```

I'm not sure this question is a duplicate of [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44958) which suggests to install the pre-compiled GDAL from [GIS internals](http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php).

Comment: Do you have anaconda?

Comment: @MarceloVilla I actually have tried to do it with Anaconda around two hours ago ([following this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34410958/2228912)), but was stuck because the versions proposed for certain packages like Django and Scikit-learn are quite old for Python3.4. Another strange thing is that using Python34 (not anaconda), gdal works well on my laptop. I cannot guess what has changed exactly so that it's now complaining about DLLs on the work machine.

Comment: `conda install gdal` worked perfectly for me and then you can update any package you want

Comment: I did the same thing as in the tutorial I linked to above, but what caused another issue for me is that my project depends on `Scikit-learn` but apparently the version for Python34 doesn't support MLP. The other problem is that the latest version of `Django` for Python34 is v1.10, and I'm afraid the majority of Django plugins have moved to Django 2.0.

Comment: Have you checked your path variables? I too had a hell of time getting GDAL to work, even among my lab full of competent GIS and comp sci folk.

Comment: @GISKid Should I add the path to the gdal package inside Python's libraries folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved by sticking with the version `3.6.5` (latest as of this answer) of Python. It turns out that I didn't have to downgrade to Python 3.4 since all the libraries I was using are compatible with Python 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on windows...
You may need to modify your system path and variables:
Add the GDAL installation directory bin folder to your system `PATH` BEFORE the python path it may be something like:

`C:\gdalwin32-1.6\bin`

Add `GDAL_Data` environment variable:
Variable name: GDAL_DATA
Variable value: C:\gdalwin32-1.6\data

Reboot your machine and then test.

Since you have a lot of niche python dependancies it may be worth-while to set up a [virtual python environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) and [how to use python virtualenv](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/how-to-use-python-virtualenv). A virtual environment is an isolated working copy of python which allows you to work on a specific project without it affecting your other projects, therefore you ca have multiple installations of python for each project.

Comment: Christoph's python distribution already contains (and adds) the gdal binaries/dlls - no need to download them from elsewhere if you opt to use them

Comment: @nickves Can the error with the DLLs come from the fact that I'm on Windows 7 on that computer? I don't have any problem on my laptop with GDAL on Windows 8.

Comment: @hakim I would also double check which versions you're installing 32-bit or 64-bit?  Is it possible to do a clean install of gdal first on the machine?

Comment: @GISKid The version of GDAL I'm struggling is the right one (64bits) for the OS I'm on. What do you mean by a clean install of gdal?

Comment: I mean, uninstall python completely, re-install using a virtual environment and/or anaconda to get GDAL working and add back all your other dependencies. Sometime's a clean slate is necessary.

Comment: Windows 10 has been freshly installed on that computer, but I still see the exact same error on Python-3.4.4. Tomorrow I'll try to set-up Docker, since I don't see any other way to find where this issue is coming from, and I don't really want to compile GDAL from the source on Windows.

Comment: Please update if you find a solution - GDAL can really be a pain in these unique situations, no doubt someone else could benefit from your exp