# GDAL installation-FAILURE: No datasource specified. Windows 10

Tags: gdal, windows, osgeo4w

I am following the below tutorial to install GDAL: https://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/tutorials/installing-gdal-for-windows
after failing to install through the OSGEO4W setup, I have updated my environments and when typing in `gdalinfo` in the command prompt I get the following:

```
C:\Users\amell>gdalinfo
Usage: gdalinfo [--help-general] [-json] [-mm] [-stats] [-hist] [-nogcp] [-nomd]
                [-norat] [-noct] [-nofl] [-checksum] [-proj4]
                [-listmdd] [-mdd domain|`all`] [-wkt_format WKT1|WKT2|...]*
                [-sd subdataset] [-oo NAME=VALUE]* datasetname

FAILURE: No datasource specified.
```

When I type in `gdaltranslator` I get the following:

```
C:\Users\amell>gdaltranslator
'gdaltranslator' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: are you trying for `gdal_translate`?

Comment: I am trying to eventually configure GeoNode

Comment: There is no program `gdaltranslator` (AFAIK) but there is one called `gdal_translate` - your `gdalinfo` response looks good to me. Try `gdalinfo --formats` to be sure

Comment: C:\Users\amell>gdal --formats
'gdal' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Use the command literally as Ian wrote it `gdalinfo --formats`. There is no program named "gdal" but "gdalinfo" does exists. Another exercise for you is to try `gdalinfo --version`.

Comment: The same procedure is in this site (gis.stackexchange.com) in following link: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44958/gdal-importerror-in-python-on-windows/143140#143140 . If you launch IDLE (Python GUI) and type **from osgeo import gdal [Enter]** without any error, you have installed GDAL. If not, you have to repeat the process until to find out where the problem is.

Comment: By the way, both tutorials are too old and you have Windows 10 (32 or 64 bits?). So, you need to adapt that procedure to your own system for installing adequate GDAL binaries and Python bindings. It is very important to know if you have a 32 or a 64 bits system because installation depends on this (your tutorial works with a 32 bits system).

Comment: I am currently getting error message GDAL 3.3.1-pp37-pyp37_pp73-win_amd64.whl is not supported wheel on this platform when pip installing Gdal in the Geonode Virtual Env. I understand the .whl version should match the installed version via OSGEO4. Tried the rest 64 bit still getting same error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The installation is ok.
`gdalinfo` tool needs a *datasetname* parameter at least, e.g `gdalinfo some_raster.tif` to get the information from *some_raster.tif*.
`gdaltranslator` is not the name of any tool provided by GDAL.