# How to export a shape polygon to a file

Tags: polygon, export

Is it possible to to export a shape polygon to a file? I want to export the polygons from a country to use them on a different map system,

Comment: what do you mean by file? Shapefiles are files. Do you mean a specific format? if so which format? What GIS software are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The most common spatial file format is a [shapefile](http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf), which your data is most likely in.  The shapefile is actually a composite of 3 mandatory files and (commonly) several ancillary files.

- .shp includes the feature geometry
- .shx an index file allowing for speedy referencing
- .dbf the feature attributes

Ancillary (often generated on-the-fly by GIS software)

- .sbn indexing
- .sbx indexing
- .prj projection
- .shp.xml spatial metadata

The conversion formats are too numerous to mention and vary widely in their application, although a few common ones are KML, ascii, .csv, spatial databases...

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable with [GDAL/OGR](http://www.gdal.org/) ([or willing to level up](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/how-to-install-gdal-with-python-on-windows)), you can use [`ogr2ogr`](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) along with [OGR SQL](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_sql.html) to quickly and easily export a single feature from any of the [OGR supported vector formats](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_formats.html) into a stand-alone shapefile. For example..

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" "C:/xGIS/Vector/test/Richland.shp" 
"C:/xGIS/Vector/COUNTIES_SC_WGS84.shp" -nlt GEOMETRY 
-sql "select * from counties_sc_wgs84 where cntyname='Richland'"
```

Here's a breakdown of this ogr2ogr statement:

- `-f` is the format we're exporting to.
- `Richland.shp` is the OUTPUT shapefile.
- `COUNTIES_SC_WGS84.shp` is the INPUT shapefile.
- `-nlt GEOMETRY` is a special condition I added for flexibility, because you never know when a shapefile of polygons has both single and multi-part polygons.
- `-sql` is the OGR SQL sentence that targets the single-feature subset I wanted from my INPUT shapefile.

There are tons of other things you could do additionally, if you wanted, like transform from one projection to another, etc.

**Gotchas and Caveats**

Note that I applied line-breaks only to aid in seeing the whole ogr2ogr statement at a glance, but that *any statement you create should not have line-breaks*.

Also *beware cutting and pasting these script parts*. I've found the terminal doesn't play well with quote and double-quote characters copied from web pages. It's best to build your ogr2ogr statement in notepad or something, then paste it into the terminal when you're ready to execute it.