# Install GDAL 2.0 on Windows

Tags: gdal, windows

Ho do I go about getting GDAL 2.0 on Windows? I can get the source from the OSGEO site http://www.osgeo.org/node/1591 but I have no idea how to compile it.

Is there not a built version of GDAL 2.0 like there is for the 1.X releases? I couldn't find an install option in the Osgeo4w installer either.

Comment: What have you tried google is full of "install gdal on Windows" tutorials and there is this...http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/installing-gdal-with-python-on-windows

Comment: Gisinternals http://gisinternals.com is the easiest alternative and it is mentioned also in https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries. OSGeo4W will move to GDAL 2.x soon but all the other software in OSGeo4W which are using GDAL must first be made to compile with GDAL 2.x.

Comment: @Dan thanks for the suggestion, however I don't see how that link helps. I have tried the Osgeo4w installer and unless I am missing something very obvious - I don't see GDAL 2.0 as an install option.

Comment: @RutgerH I want to use it via command line so I can update CartoDB tables.

Comment: Thanks @user30184 I see it under the development releases on GIS Internals!

Comment: Also see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/installing-gdal-with-python-on-windows

Answer (score 8):

The two main alternatives for installing GDAL on Windows are to use [OSGeo4W installer](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) or to use binary packages from 
[GISInternals.com](http://www.gisinternals.com/development.php).

Installation with the packages from GIS Internals is perhaps a little easier than with OSGeo4W. The site offers MSI installers but also zipped packages which can just be unzipped to disk and run even without administrator rights. With zipped packages it is also easy to have different GDAL versions on computer because all that is needed is to unzip them into different directories.

What is easier with the OSGeo4W installer is to get the Python utilities to work because it installs all GDAL, Python, and GDAL Python bindings, and sets the environment variables so that user can just run Python utilities from the OSGeo4W Shell. From GIS Internals users can install GDAL core and Python bindings from packages but they must also themselves install the proper Python version and set the environment variables.

Comment: On Gisinternals.com, you have to look out for the development packages. They come with GDAL 2.1, while the stable versions (release and branch) still have GDAL 1.11.3. Follow the information links to see what you get. So in fact, noone offers a compiled GDAL 2.0.

Comment: @AndreJ's comment re: watching for dev packages remains true, however compiled v2.x binaries are available now in both streams

Answer (score 2):

After spending forever trying to compile it myself I happened to notice that when I installed the GDAL Python bindings via [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) the GDAL 2.0 binaries came along with as well.

Path to binaries: `[anaconda root]\envs\[environment name]\Library\bin`

Path to resources: `[anaconda root]\envs\[environment name]\Library\share`