# Merging DEM Files into a Single DEM and Exporting Cropped DEM

Tags: dem, merge, clip

I am looking to combine .DEM files into a single .DEM file and export a crop of the center.

My site lies across 4 DEM files, about a quarter in each. It only occupies a small portion of each. I am using an outside program to convert DEM files into 3D data for Rhino to use as a NURBS site map. The problem is the program will combine 3 of the files, but one of the DEMs will not combine with the others reading "Out of Memory." I am thinking that if I crop just the site it will hopefully upload- as it is a much smaller area than any one of the DEMs- but again it exists across 4 separate DEM files.

Essentially, combine all 4, export out a small portion of the middle as a .DEM.

The program only works with .DEM extensions and not GeoTIFFs.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Answer (score 2):

To merge raster files into one, one can use [gdal_merge.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html). It works on a lots of raster formats (see [list here](http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html)). I suppose your .dem files comes [from USGS](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_usgsdem.html)

You should then be able, should [gdal is properly installed with the python bindings](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/installing-gdal-with-python-on-windows), to merge your files into one by using the command line in something like :

`gdal_merge.py -o mymergedem.dem mydem1.dem mydem2.dem mydem3.dem mydem4.dem`

> ***gdal_merge.py*** : This utility will automatically mosaic a set of images. All the images must be in the same coordinate system and have
>   a matching number of bands, but they may be overlapping, and at
>   different resolutions. In areas of overlap, the last image will be
>   copied over earlier ones.

You can then crop your data from coordinates or from a shapefile for example with the [gdalwarp utility](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) with something like :

`gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:[Replace with yours] -te xmin ymin xmax ymax mymergedem.dem mycropped.dem`

> ***gdalwarp*** : The gdalwarp utility is an image mosaicing, reprojection and warping utility. The program can reproject to any supported projection, and
>   can also apply GCPs stored with the image if the image is "raw" with
>   control information.

Or with [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) :

- Unprojected:`gdal_translate -srcwin xmin ymin xmax ymax mymergedem.dem mycropped.dem`
- Projected: `gdal_translate -projwin ulx uly lrx lry mymergedem.dem mycropped.dem`

> ***gdal_translate*** : The gdal_translate utility can be used to convert raster data between different formats, potentially performing some
>   operations like subsettings, resampling, and rescaling pixels in the
>   process.

To make sure it works, you might need to review the description page of the different utilities and if necessary split your question and/or search for different aspects of what could be blocking you (how to install gdal, how to use gdal_merge, how to use gdal_translate or gdalwarp).

Comment: It appears that `gdal_merge.py` does not allow `.dem` files. My error upon trying this: `Format driver USGSDEM does not support creation and piecewise writing. Please select a format that does, such as GTiff (the default) or HFA (Erdas Imagine).`